# CSS :hover and bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a navbar in bootstrap 3 and I found something weird.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div className="container-fluid">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
            Home
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
             About us
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
           Surveys
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
            Statistics
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is structure of this component and here is CSS, where I try to make `<a>` attribute larger on `:hover`

```
a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

And I can't help wondering why despite others attributes working, transform shows no effect. Not sure if it changes anything, but maybe I'll add that I use React for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only elements positioned by the box model can be transformed. As a rule of thumb, an element is positioned by the box model if it has display: block. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

You can also use `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Indeed I should have checked this property. It works now, thank you!